# Regular expression using sqlite in android

Tags: android, regex, sqlite

I having a difficulty with regex, I have a table products that of one of it`s field is a period.
I want to filter records by a period the user entered in my application.
for example the period might be 2006-2012 or just 2006-

I want to filter all the records that contain only the pattern 2006-

I tried many examples but unfortunately nothing works properly

this is my code

```
Cursor c = rDB.rawQuery("select title,price from Products,UserProducts where UserProducts.product_code=Prodcuts.product_code and USER_EMAIL=? and Products.period like '%[0-9]+%' group by UserSeries.product_code order by Products.title asc", new String[]{email});
while(c.moveToNext())
{
         //save the records 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Products.period like '%[0-9]+%'
```

[`LIKE`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#like) does not work with regexps.

To use regular expression matching, use the `REGEXP` operator. Note that by default the [`REGEXP` operator is not implemented](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like), even though the syntax supports it.

For simpler matching needs you can also consider [`GLOB`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#glob).

> I want to filter all the records that contain only the pattern 2006-

You don't need a regular expression for that.

```
Products.period like '2006-%'
```

will match anything where `period` starts with the string `2006-`.

---

> I meant any year with "-" symbol at the end

```
Products.period like '%-'
```

will match anything where `period` ends with the string `-`.

Comment: I meant any year with "-" symbol at the end, with regexp i am getting an exception
 exception android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "REGEX": syntax error (code 1)
and with glob i am not getting any records from the cursor

Comment: `REGEX` is not `REGEXP`. But it's not supported anyway. `GLOB` pattern syntax is different and similar to `LIKE` in terms of expressive power. Updated the answer.

Comment: I checked my table again and strangely the periods contain ΓÇô and not - character

Comment: To me that looks like some other dash character UTF-8 octets interpreted as ISO-8859-x.

Comment: I tried many combinations with ΓÇô but nothing seems to work properly
like '%ΓÇô' , like 'ΓÇô', in any case i don`t get any records