# android sqlite and regular expressions

Tags: android, regex, sqlite

I need to select the query from the database all the names that begin with the letter or letters, but without the letter "x".

For some titles that now exists in the following code(It's slow but it works):

```
 String qstr = "SELECT SUM("+SQLhelper.COL_COUNT +") FROM " 
               + SQLhelper.TABLE_MYDETAILS + " WHERE " +        
                         SQLhelper.COL_DETAILID + " LIKE 'sh%'" + 
                " or " + SQLhelper.COL_DETAILID + " LIKE 'sw%'" +
                " or " + SQLhelper.COL_DETAILID + " LIKE 'cty%'"+
                " or " + SQLhelper.COL_DETAILID + " LIKE 'twn%'"+
                " or " + SQLhelper.COL_DETAILID + " LIKE 'tlm%'"+
                " or " + SQLhelper.COL_DETAILID + " LIKE 'sp%'"+
                " or " + SQLhelper.COL_DETAILID + " LIKE 'rac%'"+
                " or " + SQLhelper.COL_DETAILID + " LIKE 'frnd%'"+
                " or " + SQLhelper.COL_DETAILID + " LIKE 'elf%'"+
                " or " + SQLhelper.COL_DETAILID + " LIKE 'pm%'"+
                " or " + SQLhelper.COL_DETAILID + " LIKE 'cas%'"+
                " or " + SQLhelper.COL_DETAILID + " LIKE 'oct%'"+
                " or " + SQLhelper.COL_DETAILID + " LIKE 'hp%'"+    
                " or " + SQLhelper.COL_DETAILID + " LIKE 'njo%'"+
                " or " + SQLhelper.COL_DETAILID + " LIKE 'loc%'"+
                " or " + SQLhelper.COL_DETAILID + " LIKE 'stu%'"+
                " or " + SQLhelper.COL_DETAILID + " LIKE 'iaj%'"+ 
                " or " + SQLhelper.COL_DETAILID + " LIKE 'tlr%'"+
                " or " + SQLhelper.COL_DETAILID + " LIKE 'lor%'"+
                " or " + SQLhelper.COL_DETAILID + " LIKE 'ovr%'"+
                " or " + SQLhelper.COL_DETAILID + " LIKE 'tnt%'"+
                " or " + SQLhelper.COL_DETAILID + " LIKE 'pi%'"+
                " or " + SQLhelper.COL_DETAILID + " LIKE 'idea%'"+
                " or " + SQLhelper.COL_DETAILID + " LIKE 'min%'"+
                " or " + SQLhelper.COL_DETAILID + " LIKE 'trn%'"; 
    Cursor allc = db.rawQuery(qstr, null);          
    allc.moveToFirst();        
    int cnt = allc.getInt(0);
    if(cnt==0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString( R.string.myminifigsnotfound ), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    allc.close();
```

When I add other names must be added to the query string. 
I tried to do so, using regular expressions:

```
 sql = "SELECT " + SQLhelper.COL_DETAILID + "," + SQLhelper.COL_COUNT 
      + " FROM " + SQLhelper.TABLE_INSTRUCTIONS 
     + " where " +SQLhelper.TABLE_INSTRUCTIONS_SETID + "="+setid 
       + " and "+ SQLhelper.COL_DETAILID +" LIKE '[a-wyz]%'";
```

But it does not work, it returns an empty query.
How to do it?

Comment: Do you need to filter out results that just have x as the first letter?  Or do you need to filter out results that have x as any of the first three characters?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression using sqlite in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20907914/regular-expression-using-sqlite-in-android)

Comment: I need a filter value starts any letters except the letter "x".
Example are the values: x12412, 424226, cty35353, twn545. Output only: cty35353, twn545

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's a little bit late to answer this question , but I put it here for people who may face the same problem later. For using REGEXP operator in Android's Sqlite you can use the library SqliteRE :

https://github.com/mobi-life/sqlitere

It also supports optional feature for encrypting data if you want.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember regular expressions (`REGEXP`) are one of the few things that are not supported in SQLite on Android. There are just some placeholders that work with `LIKE`, these are `%` and `_`.

What you could do instead is, turn your query:

```
SELECT SUM("+SQLhelper.COL_COUNT +")
  FROM SQLhelper.TABLE_MYDETAILS
 WHERE INSTR ('sh|sw|...',   SUBSTR(SQLhelper.COL_DETAILID, 1, 2)) > 0
    OR INSTR ('cty|twn|...', SUBSTR(SQLhelper.COL_DETAILID, 1, 3)) > 0;
```