# Android Sqlite get rows where first character is not an Alphabet

Tags: android, regex, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to return rows from a specific column where the first character is not an alphabet (A-Z)

I tried many solutions I found from other questions on stackoverflow, but none worked

```
query = "SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE columnName REGEXP '^[A-z]%'";
```

This returns no results.

I want to return results as: 1example, @example .. etc. Also results in non English language.

Comment: I don't speak sqlite, but if you want *not* in a character class you need to start it with ^, like `REGEXP '^[^a-zA-Z]'` - the first ^ means start of string and the second one means 'character not in this list'

Comment: I tried that as well, but it returns the same result = none :(

Comment: @MoDev how about `^[0-9]`?

Comment: Still returns none

Comment: The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28772467/android-sqlite-and-regular-expressions) say that Android sqlite doesn't support `REGEXP` (it has to be manually enabled with a user defined function and that isn't done by the android bindings) but they're a few years old so things *might* have changed. Guess not though if those fixed REs aren't working.

Comment: Thanks @Shawn, you are correct

Comment: The odd thing is that using `REGEXP` isn't giving an error as that's the default behavior. *The REGEXP operator is a special syntax for the regexp() user function. No regexp() user function is defined by default and so use of the REGEXP operator will normally result in an error message. If an application-defined SQL function named "regexp" is added at run-time, then the "X REGEXP Y" operator will be implemented as a call to "regexp(Y,X)".* - from [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#glob)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try the GLOB operator?

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE columnName GLOB '[^A-z]*'
```

Comment: WORKS like a charm :)

Comment: That will fail to match strings starting with any of the characters [, \, ], _, ^ and \`, btw.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Shawn, however it will not affect my current usage of it.